# How to create a Calculated Column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I'm working on a sports bookkeeping project and would like to create a calculated field. There are four values that are of interest:
risk: how much was risked
odds: a float value (e.g 2.5)
result: 'W', 'L', 'D' for win, lose or draw
returned: calculated field

The returned value can be determined as follows:

```
if (result == 'W'){
    $returned = $risked*odds
}
else if ($result == 'L') {
    $returned = $risked*-1
}
else {
    $returned = 0
}
```

But I'm at a loss as to how to create that calculated column.

Comment: mysql does not support auto calculated columns, use stored procedures, triggers or server-side (php I suppose) code to do the calculation

Comment: Do you mean it will be a column in your **table** or just in your SELECT query **results**?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a table named *tablename* with fields named *risked*, *odds*, and *result*, with this query you will select the 3 fields plus the calculated one, called *returned*:

```
SELECT 
    result,
    risked,
    odds, 
    CASE result
        WHEN 'W' then risked*odds
        WHEN 'L' then risked*-1
        ELSE 0
        END as returned
FROM tablename;
```

It's not a column per se, but you can create a *view* with this select.